# PowerShell's Stop-Job / StopJob() takes 2 minutes to stop job

Tags: c#, powershell

I have written a library using C# and use it within a PowerShell script.  The C# library loads a large amount of data into a database.  I am using `Start-Job` to kick off the process and I am monitoring a file for errors.

However, I have found that even a simple `while` loop in C# cannot be stopped (takes two whole minutes).

My C#:

```
namespace SampleJobDLL
{
    public class ClassX
    {
        public void MethodY()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell:

```
$scriptBlock = {

    Add-Type -Path ".\SampleJobDLL.dll"

    $classX = New-Object SampleJobDLL.ClassX

    $classX.MethodY();
}

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Then running the following script:

```
$before = [DateTime]::Now; 
$job.StopJob(); 
$after = [DateTime]::Now; 
$after.Subtract($before);
```

Gives me:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 2
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 4
```

Is there any method of running code using `Start-Job` (or equivalent command) but being able to stop it immediately?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to kill it through PS or C#?  If you are at the PS command line, Ctrl + C should kill it.

Comment: A job cannot be stopped using control+c because It runs in its own space.

Comment: Get the processID of the job and kill it in another instance of PS?

Comment: In your example that calls WriteLine in a loop you might try adding code to that sleeps periodically for short periods of time or similar - anything so that the new job (which is in a different process) is not totally CPU bound. Killing the process as dfundako suggests, is another good possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that dfundako and user2460798 are right: it is easiest to spawn a new process and kill it, rather than messing around with PowerShell Jobs.

Put the script block contents in a new file; call it (e.g) `MyScript.ps1`.

Thereafter, we launch the script using Start-Process and capture the process object in a variable:

```
$process = Start-Process powershell.exe '.\MyScript.ps1' -PassThru
```

Kill it using

```
$process.Kill();
```

or

```
Stop-Process -Id $process.Id -Force
```

I have looked into creating a PowerShell instance using  `[PowerShell]::Create()` but a command cannot be invoked against an instance while it is running some other code.

Also looked into spawning a new thread, which does not work (even if I pass in `-Mta` as a command line arg to powershell.exe).